# Flexbox usage vs other approaches. Which is more performant and better overall today?

Tags: css, flexbox

I do not claim to be any kind of an expert, but I have been writing CSS grid layout styles for a while (a little over 19 years on and off). I have used styles the way I learned them growing up after my Highschool years in the early 2000s for a long time (which is what some new or younger developers have told me is the "old school way," nowadays).

My "old school way" of writing styles doesn't use flexbox at all, but rather uses position, display, and other types of properties to create block-level layouts and CSS layout grids also utilizing widths, margins, padding, box-sizing, and wrapping with tricks like using font-size: 0; to eliminate extra spacing between grid items, etc. , etc. Though this is a familiar way and a way of writing styles that I've come to trust and become accustomed to overtime, I also realize it takes a lot of effort, more code, and there can be more "bugs" to work out at times, so I've also learned how to achieve layout with Flexbox.

Flexbox was fairly simple for me to learn, understand, and implement in sites that I write for today. I've used Flexbox for over the last three years and have grown to like it. However, I do find at times that it can still be very useful to know the old way when it comes to legacy browser support, and recently I stumbled across some reading that indicates Flexbox may not be as performant as my "old school way" of writing CSS grid layout styles.

I typically write code for small agencies and startups with little oversight which allows me a lot of freedom to do things the way I want to, but these environments can also lack structure and direction when it comes to best practices for quality production code.

So, I'm here pose a question to the experts: What is the best approach for the writing of CSS styles for layout in production today? What have you found to be the most performant with the least overhead, and to be the most reliable approach? Is Flexbox as widely adopted as I've been lead to believe by some of my cohorts?

Comment: You are as an expert as anyone else, if 19 years of experience don't count as expert then I don't know what is. What you write depends on what your supported browsers are, flex can generally be safely used, grid has decent support as well. If you need to support old IEs like ie10 then I can only pray for you

Comment: I also have a bunch of years on my back, but not as much as you do. You are the expert here actually haha. Just a small comment here. Flexbox may be less performant, but is really really really worht it (for me). Nowadays you will rarely see any performance problems when using flexbox, and being so easy to achieve, reducing bugs and such, I'll stick with it as it allows me to waste less time on the CSS. With flexboxes I forgot the last time I used `float` xD[...]

Comment: [...]Is like ES6 vs ES5 when using JavaScript. Surely a `for(var i = 0;...` loop is way faster that some fancy syntax ES6 gives to you, specially when you concat a map with a reduce with something else (ES5 though), but when you are going to loop though a small array of 10 elements, ES6 is way cleaner, hence having less bugs over time, which is kinda good. WHen I have to look for performance, I do, but when I want to code fast with less bugs and a bunch of ms up or down doesn't matter, I also do like so. Depends a lot on the project (or "section"? don't know how to call it, but you get me).